# When is the available 'language: English French...' link displayed under translatable content?

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I am struggling with the i18n configuration of my site and the display of the available translated content 'languages' link displayed next/under the content.

Under which condition will this link be displayed for translated content?

1. The content type is translated-enabled
2. The language field must be displayed/visible in the content type configuration
3. There must be more than one language made available
4. The content must be translated
5. ...?

I guess all the above apply, but is there more?

The reason I am asking this is because I believe I have configured my site properly, but I still don't see that link to jump between translated content. I am looking for a check list to find my error(s) or misunderstanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is your other question!

I'm not exactly sure but I just did this from scratch on my Drupal test site and found it to work.

1. **Modules** - The only module I have enabled is **Multilingual content**
2. **Content Type** - **Edit** - **Publishing options** - Enabled, with translation
3. **Content Type** - **Edit** - **Multilingual settings** - Nothing selected except 'Normal'
4. **Regional and language** - **Languages** - Multiple languages enabled
5. **Regional and language** - **Multilingual settings** - **Node Options** - Hide content translation links is not checked

i18n can definitely be uncooperative...

Comment: Problem solved, not really sure why. I believe it has to do with modification of content instance and change of 'Require language (Do not allow Language Neutral)' configuration.

Comment: This doesn't surprise me. I've had i18n start working after disabling and re-enabling translation.